# Is there any way to get a JavaScript object's property name/s using property value/s?

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

Say I have a JavaScript object like so:

```
var myObject = {
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  key3: "value3"
}
```

We all know I can get `value1` by using `myObject ['key1']`, but is there any way to do the reverse, like `myObject ["value1"]` returning `'key1'`?

I understand that I can use

```
var values = Object.values (myObject);
var index = values.indexOf ("value1");
var keys = Object.keys (myObject);
keys [index];
```

to do this, but that's just long-winded. I also understand that this would be even more cumbersome when multiple keys have the same value. I'm just wondering if there is some other way to make doing something like this easier.

Comment: Why don't you just flip the key/values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make an object that reverses the keys and values, then use ordinary property lookup:

```js
var myObject = {
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  key3: "value3"
}
var reversedObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(myObject).map(entries => entries.reverse())
);

console.log(reversedObj.value1);
console.log(reversedObj.value3);
```

Though, keep in mind that this depends on the values being unique.

If you need to distinguish string values from non-string values, eg `key1: 123` vs `key2: '123'`, use a Map instead (since plain objects can only have string (and symbol) keys, but Map keys can be *any type*)

```js
var myObject = {
  key1: 123,
  key2: "123",
  key3: "value3"
}
var reversedMap = new Map(
  Object.entries(myObject).map(entries => entries.reverse())
);

console.log(reversedMap.get('123'));
console.log(reversedMap.get(123));
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the quick response. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can iterate over keys and filter by values:
Values don't have to be unique, you will get an array of keys.
And you don't have to reverse an object beforehand.

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
const value = 1;
const keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === value);
console.log(keys);
```

Comment: Thanks. This will be great to use when the values aren't unique.

Comment: If you want just one value you can replace `filter` with `find`.

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind the accepted answer doesn't work with numerical values and it's much slower.